# Can't log in to my Debian system via the GUI

Tags: debian, login

I am suddenly not able to log into my Debian 8.5 system via the Desktop.
I can still log in when I am in the TTY.

I was using Gnome, now when I enter my password the page goes black shortly and then I get back to the login page, without any messages or warnings.

I was actually trying to install the allegro5 library.  At some point when I hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key for autocompletion of commands I got this warning:

```
bash: cannot temp file for here-document: No space left on device.
```

I also get this error when I hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> in TTY for command-completion.

What should I do? Can any one help?

Answer (score 2):

Try `df -h`

Probably you have no space left.

If you can`t login in any way, try single user from the first step of boot.

[Debian-boot-to-single-user-mode](https://serverfault.com/questions/482079/debian-boot-to-single-user-mode)
And then clear some space or eventually add some more.

Comment: What can i do with the output of `df -h` command?

Comment: See if is about space.

Comment: if the OP has the error "no space left..." of course it is about space.

Comment: How can i free space? And which space is critical to be freed?

Comment: You will have to free space where is 100%
First search what occupy the most of the space 
<code>
 find /path -xdev -size +100M -exec ls -lah {} \; 
</code>
Don't know exactly what you have there.. .you have to figure out by yourself what you don't need.
If you don't have what to delete, you will have to add more space. add a disk or extend if you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You have no space left on /tmp or / (root) partitions. Just clean it up.

Comment: Or if the `$HOME` partition is separate then that might be full