# Ubuntu says disk space is exhausted. No terminal access. Only guest log on. HOW can I erase disk space now?

Tags: linux, login, disk

I have the latest Ubuntu, fifteen ( my five key is toasted and my onboard isn't loading). After a software update, my computer went blank. I can log on as guest or as usual but have to open a blank file with firefox to get to the internet. In any event, zero access to terminal. No matter what buttons I press, it keeps saying "disk space is exhausted". Now, I knew that was an issue with me from the get go. I have bleach bit and run it almost every day. I am uncomfortable with partition usage as I am not sure what I am doing to navigate them properly. In any event, I got nothing. I do have a USB with a backup on it, but it will NOT load.

Comment: Can you boot to a live environment and delete files from there?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Can you log in at one of the CLI virtual terminals (Ctrl-Alt-F1 thru Ctrl-Alt-F6)?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301214/ .

Comment: Nope. Zero success at the virtual commands. It only says the disk is full : "disk space is exhausted".

Comment: Virtual terminals will not work as it keeps saying "disk space exhausted". I've tried that for 2 days to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

If the only issue is clearing up disk space, you could do that from any live Linux environment. Let's use Ubuntu's, because it sounds like you're used to it anyways.

**What you will need:**

1. The latest live image from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
2. A USB flash drive, 2GB or more.
3. A computer to use to download the disk image and 'burn' it to the flash drive. (Windows, Linux, or OSX).
4. A program to 'burn' the image to the flash drive with. ([rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) for Windows, unetbootin for Linux/OSX.)

Once you have everything, flash the image to the flash drive (both programs are pretty straight forward, and Google is your friend)
.

You will need to find out which button to press to select boot device on your computer, this is different for every computer, although the most common is F12, followed by F9 and F8. Once you found it, insert the flash drive into a USB port, power on the computer and hold the boot select button until a menu appears. Select the flash drive and wait for Ubuntu to boot. You should then have an option to "try" Ubuntu or something along those lines, select it. Once you're at the desktop, open up a terminal and type `lsblk`. This will show you all of the different disks and partitions on your computer. Determine which is the system partition and mount it to /mnt with `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` where /dev/sda1 is your system partition. Now that you have your system partition mounted, you can clear up storage to avoid the error. Once you're done, unmount the filesystem with `umount /mnt`
, and reboot the system. Everything should work fine.

Comment: I'll try this now.

Comment: @Christine any luck?